# How to make Tube behave like Line when working with non-ideally scaled data?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, visualization

I have a set of data that `Line` enjoys quite well, however, `Tube` seems to throw something of a tantrum when I deliver the same set of data. The data:

```
data = {{-1214.2199935658107`,-848.2705321806565`,-0.00001416666666666664`},{-1244.2463057872262`,-804.5024679750907`,-0.000013333333333333296`},{-1272.6743663132045`,-759.6590618571543`,-0.000012499999999999979`},{-1299.4664556851817`,-713.7981785755134`,-0.000011666666666666634`},{-1324.5865758011587`,-666.978491137754`,-0.000010833333333333317`},{-1348.0004016604767`,-619.2595928877795`,-9.999999999999972`*^-6},{-1369.6752736128424`,-570.7021396907099`,-9.166666666666655`*^-6},{-1389.5802339318311`,-521.3680065458933`,-8.33333333333331`*^-6},{-1407.6861084082525`,-471.32044184944846`,-7.4999999999999655`*^-6},{-1423.9656304860086`,-420.62420257475856`,-6.666666666666648`*^-6},{-1438.3936024494813`,-369.34565482908965`,-5.8333333333333306`*^-6},{-1450.9470855141483`,-317.5528264957635`,-4.999999999999959`*^-6},{-1461.6056085442237`,-265.31540183164884`,-4.1666666666666415`*^-6},{-1470.3513836617653`,-212.70465174468688`,-3.333333333333324`*^-6},{-1477.169516316059`,-159.79329776504858`,-2.4999999999999523`*^-6},{-1482.0481974956165`,-106.65531215558806`,-1.666666666666635`*^-6},{-1484.9788666805996`,-53.3656608828774`,-8.333333333333174`*^-7},{-1485.9563357913094`,-1.0921533706287417`*^-11,0.`},{-1484.9788666806012`,53.36566088285824`,8.333333333333717`*^-7},{-1482.0481974956178`,106.6553121555689`,1.6666666666666891`*^-6},{-1477.1695163160618`,159.79329776502965`,2.5000000000000066`*^-6},{-1470.351383661767`,212.70465174466793`,3.3333333333333782`*^-6},{-1461.6056085442272`,265.3154018316305`,4.166666666666696`*^-6},{-1450.9470855141521`,317.55282649574525`,5.000000000000013`*^-6},{-1438.3936024494853`,369.3456548290715`,5.833333333333385`*^-6},{-1423.9656304860139`,420.62420257474065`,6.666666666666702`*^-6},{-1407.6861084082593`,471.320441849431`,7.50000000000002`*^-6},{-1389.5802339318382`,521.3680065458755`,8.333333333333337`*^-6},{-1369.67527361285`,570.7021396906931`,9.166666666666709`*^-6},{-1348.0004016604855`,619.2595928877626`,0.000010000000000000026`},{-1324.58657580117`,666.9784911377373`,0.000010833333333333344`},{-1299.4664556851928`,713.7981785754989`,0.000011666666666666715`}};
```

Is inputted into:

```
Grid[{{Graphics3D[{
     {Darker[Green, 2/3], Thickness[0.01], 
      Arrowheads[{{0.1}}, Appearance -> "Projected"], Arrow[Tube[data]]}
     
     }, AlignmentPoint -> Center, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    AutomaticImageSize -> False, Axes -> False, AxesEdge -> None, 
    AxesLabel -> None, AxesOrigin -> {1650.`, -1650.`, -0.00025`}, 
    AxesStyle -> {}, Background -> None, 
    BaselinePosition -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> {}, Boxed -> False, 
    BoxRatios -> {3.2`, 3.2`, 6.5`}, BoxStyle -> {}, 
    ClipPlanes -> None, ClipPlanesStyle -> Automatic, 
    ColorOutput -> Automatic, ContentSelectable -> Automatic, 
    ControllerLinking -> Automatic, ControllerMethod -> Automatic, 
    ControllerPath -> Automatic, CoordinatesToolOptions -> Automatic, 
    DisplayFunction -> Identity, Epilog -> {}, FaceGrids -> None, 
    FaceGridsStyle -> {}, FormatType -> TraditionalForm, 
    ImageMargins -> 0.`, ImagePadding -> All, ImageSize -> 500.`, 
    ImageSizeRaw -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> {}, 
    Lighting -> Automatic, Method -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> None, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2475.`, 
       1815.0000000000002`}, {-1815.0000000000002`, 
       2475.`}, {-0.00032500000000000004`, 0.00032500000000000004`}}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, PlotRegion -> Automatic, 
    PreserveImageOptions -> Automatic, Prolog -> {}, 
    RotationAction -> "Fit", SphericalRegion -> True, Ticks -> None, 
    TicksStyle -> {}, TouchscreenAutoZoom -> False, 
    ViewAngle -> 0.33632810973764027`, 
    ViewCenter -> {0.5`, 0.5`, 0.5`}, ViewMatrix -> Automatic, 
    ViewPoint -> {-1.9461497767487252`, 1.477527579217831`, 
      2.340814665690469`}, ViewProjection -> Automatic, 
    ViewRange -> All, ViewVector -> Automatic, 
    ViewVertical -> {0.23556268765910476`, -0.24706981260320413`, 
      0.9399291079028442`}], Graphics3D[{
     {Darker[Green, 2/3], Thickness[0.01], 
      Arrowheads[{{0.1}}, Appearance -> "Projected"], Arrow[Line[data]]}
     
     }, AlignmentPoint -> Center, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    AutomaticImageSize -> False, Axes -> False, AxesEdge -> None, 
    AxesLabel -> None, AxesOrigin -> {1650.`, -1650.`, -0.00025`}, 
    AxesStyle -> {}, Background -> None, 
    BaselinePosition -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> {}, Boxed -> False, 
    BoxRatios -> {3.2`, 3.2`, 6.5`}, BoxStyle -> {}, 
    ClipPlanes -> None, ClipPlanesStyle -> Automatic, 
    ColorOutput -> Automatic, ContentSelectable -> Automatic, 
    ControllerLinking -> Automatic, ControllerMethod -> Automatic, 
    ControllerPath -> Automatic, CoordinatesToolOptions -> Automatic, 
    DisplayFunction -> Identity, Epilog -> {}, FaceGrids -> None, 
    FaceGridsStyle -> {}, FormatType -> TraditionalForm, 
    ImageMargins -> 0.`, ImagePadding -> All, ImageSize -> 500.`, 
    ImageSizeRaw -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> {}, 
    Lighting -> Automatic, Method -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> None, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2475.`, 
       1815.0000000000002`}, {-1815.0000000000002`, 
       2475.`}, {-0.00032500000000000004`, 0.00032500000000000004`}}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, PlotRegion -> Automatic, 
    PreserveImageOptions -> Automatic, Prolog -> {}, 
    RotationAction -> "Fit", SphericalRegion -> True, Ticks -> None, 
    TicksStyle -> {}, TouchscreenAutoZoom -> False, 
    ViewAngle -> 0.33632810973764027`, 
    ViewCenter -> {0.5`, 0.5`, 0.5`}, ViewMatrix -> Automatic, 
    ViewPoint -> {-1.9461497767487252`, 1.477527579217831`, 
      2.340814665690469`}, ViewProjection -> Automatic, 
    ViewRange -> All, ViewVector -> Automatic, 
    ViewVertical -> {0.23556268765910476`, -0.24706981260320413`, 
      0.9399291079028442`}]}}]
```

Which gives:
[image: Plot of the provided data showing problem with Tube versus Line]

## Why does `Tube` treat this set of data so much differently than `Line`? What can be done to make `Tube` work as expected?

Scaling does nothing to fix this issue.

Comment: It seems like your choice of 'BoxRatios' is causing your problem. Try removing it and things seem to appear normal

Comment: @Dunlop that would be unfortunate as this is part of a much larger graphic. I don’t understand why that would be the issue, though. It seems to be ignoring the z-axis part of the data, within `Tube`. That also doesn’t give any insight as to why Line is successful. I will see what happens.

Comment: @CATrevillian `Line` is successful because it has no three-dimensional thickness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be vastly simplified. It involves `BoxRatios`, the fact that your data is essentially flat, and you are forcing it to a non-flat form factor which will scale the `Tube` to be very non-circular. Consider the following:

```
With[{data = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0.001}}},
 Grid[{{
    Graphics3D[Arrow[Tube[data]], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}], 
    Graphics3D[Arrow[Line[data]], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]}}]]
```

> [image]

Your arrow has become essentially a wall as the tube has been stretched on the z axis. Without forced ratios it's flat, but much more sensible:

```
With[{data = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0.001}}},
 Grid[{{
    Graphics3D[Arrow[Tube[data]]],
    Graphics3D[Arrow[Line[data]]]}}]]
```

> [image]

You can play tricks with your data and `Tube`s, though:

```
Module[{
  data = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0.001}},
  boxratios = {1, 1, 1},
  plotrange, scaling},
 plotrange = CoordinateBounds@data;
 scaling = boxratios/(#2 - #1 & @@@ plotrange);
 Grid[{{
    Graphics3D[
     Scale[Arrow[Tube[ScalingTransform[scaling]@data]], 1/scaling, {0, 0, 0}],
     PlotRange -> plotrange, BoxRatios -> boxratios],
    Graphics3D[Arrow[Line[data]],
     PlotRange -> plotrange, BoxRatios -> boxratios]}}]]
```

> [image]

If you know both your `PlotRange` and `BoxRatios` you can compensate for these things with some ease:

Here the "flat" data is first stretched with `ScalingTransform` to 1:1:1 form factor, then the tubed arrow graphics primitive is created, and then graphics primitives are `Scale`d back to flat form - which is again stretched to shape of a cube with `BoxRatios`...

Comment: So the use of `Tube` here is then unfeasible? How can `Tube` be made to work with this scale? I use the `BoxRatios` to enhance the difference to combat the flatness. As I experienced, even scaling the z axis did not fix the issue, though the `BoxRatios` remained in use then. Unfortunately, the `BoxRatios` are seemingly important. Perhaps scaling the z axis will fix the need for them, so I will try this.

Comment: @CATrevillian I added a hint on how one can start working around this.

Comment: Cool, that works for one set of data, but when you introduce another that has the same flatness, they get pushed to either side of the box...I don't know then if the issue is with `ScalingTransformation` or `Scale`. You can't seem to wrap `Scale` around multiple primitives. This is the "middle" of a larger set of data, made slightly larger in the x and y. Each works separately with the scaling method, but to plot them together creates the edge localization of the flat curves on either side of the box. FIXED IT!

Comment: @CATrevillian They were related to `Scale`. I tried to improve the answer a bit.

Comment: @CA This works when you put in the correct syntax! Now, to properly color it....and scale everything else ;S Wunderbar! Bellissimo!

Comment: The combination of `ScalingTransformation` and `Scale` is what did the trick :D {And proper syntax! (; }