# Plot planes of 3D vectors without severe scale distortion

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I need to visualize a few planes/slices of a 3D vector field. The first plot with only one slice is fine. Now I want to plot three slices of vectors together. And I need to **separate the three planes with enough empty space** in order to put something else in between. To this end, I use `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 4}` below. But it strongly distorts the vectors.

Is there any way to keep a 'normal' looking of the vectors? If any wildly different method, e.g., without using `BoxRatios`, it's surely as well welcome.

```
d = {-y, x, 0}; dp0 = 0.1; dp = -{0, 0, 0.06};
vec = 2 (dp0 z - d . dp) d + (z^2 - dp0^2 + dp . dp - 
     d . d) (-dp); vec = vec/Norm[vec];
xymax = 0.5; zlst = 0.16 {1, 0, -1}; dz = 0.05;
SliceVectorPlot3D[vec, 
 z == zlst[[1]], {x, -xymax, xymax}, {y, -xymax, xymax}, {z, 
  zlst[[1]] + 3 dz, zlst[[1]] - 3 dz},  
 VectorColorFunction -> {"Rainbow", #6 &}, PlotStyle -> LightGray, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Medium]
SliceVectorPlot3D[vec, 
 Table[z == zlst[[i]], {i, 3}], {x, -xymax, xymax}, {y, -xymax, 
  xymax}, {z, zlst[[1]] + dz, zlst[[3]] - dz}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> {"Rainbow", #6 &}, PlotStyle -> LightGray, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 4}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you simply remove the option `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 4}`, it gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCu3m.jpg). Isn't this what you want ?

Comment: No. As I said, I need space between the planes.

Comment: a side note : the code of the OP works only once on my machine. I don't know why. If it's general for everybody, it would be good that the OP is aware of that, because it could be (one of) the reasons of a lack of answers.

Comment: @andre314 Really?? I don't spot anything suspicious in the code and it seems to plot well.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215373/how-to-make-tube-behave-like-line-when-working-with-non-ideally-scaled-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SliceVectorPlot3D[
  vec,
  Table[z == zlst[[i]], {i, 3}],
  {x, -xymax, xymax}, {y, -xymax, xymax}, {z, zlst[[1]] + dz, 
   zlst[[3]] - dz},
  VectorColorFunction -> {"Rainbow", #6 &},
  PlotStyle -> LightGray,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 4},
  ImageSize -> Large
  ] /. a_Arrow :> Scale[a, {1, 1, 1/4}]
```

[image]

This works by simply applying [`Scale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale.html) to each of the arrows to rescale their vertical dimension to 1/4, to compensate for the scaling done by `BoxRatios`.

Comment: Nice answer, thank you!