# How to prevent vectors from flattening when using an oblong domain?

Tags: plotting

In plotting a 3d vector fields using VectorPlot3D[] with one domain length longer than the others, the vector shapes (both head and tube) flatten to account for the longer length domain. This can make the plot look pretty ugly.

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 5}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 VectorPoints -> 3, VectorAspectRatio -> .2]
```

[image]

It makes sense why they are being flattened since the domain length in the x-dimensions is 6 whereas the others are 2.  I would like them not to appear flattened.  Is there a way to normalize all the vector shapes so this doesn't happen?

Note - Interesting that neither the head nor stem flatten in 2-dimensional vector fields when using VectorPlot[]

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269289)

Comment: Seems have been fixed in 13.1 version.

Comment: @cvgmt  Possibly, but I just tried the code in the wolfram cloud which is running 13.1 (as stated at the bottom of Steven Wolfram's blog June 29th press release) and doesn't seem to be fixed there.  Can anyone confirm whether or not the issue has been fixed in the 13.1 desktop version?

Comment: I confirm that it have been fixed in 13.1.  The www.wolframcloud.com maybe use another 3D render method so it is difference with the result of Win + 13.1.

Comment: Great!  Time to upgrade.  ; )

Answer (score 1):

Per cvgmt, version 13.1 fixes my issue.  However, for those interested, here is a solution that works in previous versions by scaling the vectors using a replacement rule.

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 5}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, VectorAspectRatio -> .2, VectorPoints -> 5] /. 
 a_Arrow :> Scale[a, {1, 1/3, 1/3}]
```

[image]
Thanks to "J. M.'s slightly less busy" for the reference.